# Turn dataframe into dictionary of row series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, iteration

I need to iterate (vector operation not possible) over a very large dataframe (10 million x 70). df.iterrows and directly accessing the dataframe using df.loc[i, col] is way too slow. In the past I would first turn the dataframe to a dictionary of dictionaries which allowws me to iterate very quickly. However, this method takes up a lot of memory and is not feasible anymore for my current data.

I need to sacrifice some lookup speed to save memory. What is the best way to do this? Would turning my dataframe into an dictionary of row series {index: Series} work?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want them as a series rather than a dict or named tuple?

Comment: could you provide sample output/inpu, i attempted an answer based on what i think your looking for.

Comment: Converting the rows to Series is almost certainly a bad idea. Can we get some more context for this? What does your data look like?

Comment: I added some context to the question. The gist is that i a dict of dict takes up too much memory.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
In [1112]: pd.DataFrame(df.reset_index().to_dict(orient='records'))                                                                                                                                        
Out[1112]: 
   index  id  block check
0      0   6     25   yes
1      1   6     32    no
2      2   9     18   yes
3      3  12     17    no
4      4  15     23   yes
5      5  15     11   yes
6      6  15     15   yes

In [1113]: df.reset_index().to_dict(orient='records')                                                                                                                                                      
Out[1113]: 
[{'index': 0, 'id': 6, 'block': 25, 'check': 'yes'},
 {'index': 1, 'id': 6, 'block': 32, 'check': 'no'},
 {'index': 2, 'id': 9, 'block': 18, 'check': 'yes'},
 {'index': 3, 'id': 12, 'block': 17, 'check': 'no'},
 {'index': 4, 'id': 15, 'block': 23, 'check': 'yes'},
 {'index': 5, 'id': 15, 'block': 11, 'check': 'yes'},
 {'index': 6, 'id': 15, 'block': 15, 'check': 'yes'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could just do this (thanks @oppressionslayer for the example df):

```
df

   id  block check
0   6     25   yes
1   6     32    no
2   9     18   yes
3  12     17    no
4  15     23   yes
5  15     11   yes
6  15     15   yes

df.to_dict('index')
```

output:

```
{0: {'id': 6, 'block': 25, 'check': 'yes'}, 1: {'id': 6, 'block': 32, 'check': 'no'}, 2: {'id': 9, 'block': 18, 'check': 'yes'}, 3: {'id': 12, 'block': 17, 'check': 'no'}, 4: {'id': 15, 'block': 23, 'check': 'yes'}, 5: {'id': 15, 'block': 11, 'check': 'yes'}, 6: {'id': 15, 'block': 15, 'check': 'yes'}}
```

if you specifically (for some reason) want it to be `{index:series}` you could do this, which can be accessed the same way (i.e. `df_name[i][col]`)

```
df.T.to_dict('series')
```